# back button hangs/functionality is delayed when exiting an activity in android

Tags: android

1.I have an android client application in which i am grabbing frames from the camera and    writing them into the socket.

2.There is some communication between server and client before each frame is sent, so that i have to use functions like inbuffer.readLine().

3.When this activity starts, i create a separate thread for sending frames in onResume().

4.The problem is that while the frames are being sent, if i press the back button, it takes around 5-6 seconds ( the preview keeps running and frames are still being sent ) to go back to previous activity or may not even listen to the touch !!

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me as to how i can overcome this issue. Thankyou !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would help solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot ! works just fine ! did not use it earlier as was not sure of its functionality.
But still i have a lag of maybe 1 second. Can it be because of the time it takes to free the camera resources and freeing the callbackBuffers i have used ?

Comment: No problem!

Honestly, I don't know. I'm pretty new to Android but I knew that AsyncTasks help with freezing while the app "thinks". I'm guessing it's because of the camera resources. It takes awhile for the camera to send info/start up etc. It's kind of just how it works. Even my default Camera app takes a bit to start up.